# Error while running mule server

Tags: java, mule

I have created a flow to compress a file from the Mule end, but I got an error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: There are at least 2 connectors matching protocol "file", so the connector to use must be specified on the endpoint using the 'connector' property/attribute. Connectors in your configuration that support "file" are: input, output,

This is the flow:

```
<flow name="GZipCompress" doc:name="GZipCompress"> 
 <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:backuptest" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"> 
 <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="abc.doc" caseSensitive="false" /> 
 </file:inbound-endpoint> <string-to-byte-array-transformer doc:name="String to Byte Array" /> 
 <logger message="Payload size before compression : #[Integer.parseInt(payload.size())/1024] KB" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
<!-- If you send gzip a String then it gets serialized and mess ends up in the gzip file. To avoid this convert to byte[] first --> 
 <gzip-compress-transformer /> <logger message="Payload size after compression : #[Integer.parseInt(payload.size())/1024] KB" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" /> 
 <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:backuptestnewfolder" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" /> </flow>
```

Comment: <flow name="GZipCompress" doc:name="GZipCompress"> 
 <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:backuptest" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"> 
 <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="abc.doc" caseSensitive="false" /> 
 </file:inbound-endpoint> <string-to-byte-array-transformer doc:name="String to Byte Array" />

Comment: <logger message="Payload size before compression : #[Integer.parseInt(payload.size())/1024] KB" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" /> 
 <!-- If you send gzip a String then it gets serialized and mess ends up in the gzip file. To avoid this convert to byte[] first --> 
 <gzip-compress-transformer /> <logger message="Payload size after compression : #[Integer.parseInt(payload.size())/1024] KB" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" /> 
 <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:backuptestnewfolder" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" /> </flow>

Comment: Please put all the relevant information *in the question*, clearly formatted, without the shouty all-caps.

Answer (score 0):

> There are at least 2 connectors matching protocol "file", so the connector to use must be specified on the endpoint using the 'connector' property/attribute. Connectors in your configuration that support "file" are: input, output,

This error is stating that you've defined you `file global connectors` and now `mule` doesn't know which one to attach your stated file endpoint to. One solution is to define `connector-ref` property in your file inbound endpoint and refer to `input` connector you've defined.

```
<file:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="input" path="C:backuptest" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
```